# How do you validate against more than one regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have this validation:

```
validates :url,     :uniqueness => true,
                    :format => { :with => /^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/}
```

I want to let `url` match either the regex above or another regex. How do I add this second regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put both regexes into one regex using the 'bar' operator which does an 'or' for you:

```
/(^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)|helloworld)/
```

Matches a URL or a string containing "helloworld"

Comment: is there a space before and after the bar operator?

Comment: nope - that would force there to be spaces in the strings you are matching